# How to get a page's full URL using the Core Service?

Tags: 2013, core-service

I have a Core Service app which shows links to published pages on the staging site, for this I am trying to get the page URL from the `PageData` object, but I cannot find a property for this? Is there any easy way to do this? I guess I can build it by traversing the structure groups, getting the page template etc, but that seems a bit of an effort compared to the equivalent TOM.NET: `Page.PublishLocationUrl`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to cast `LocationInfo` to `PublishLocationInfo`, something like this:

```
((PublishLocationInfo)page.LocationInfo).PublishLocationUrl
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835630/retrieving-published-url-of-a-tridion-page-based-on-uri