# How to Read the Tridion Page URL from the publication using Core Services?

Tags: web8.5, content-delivery, core-service, sdl-tridion

I have a list of Tridion page URL's in an excel sheet, which should be unpublished on Click of a button for which I am developing a custom page.

How do I read the URL from the publication.? For example, the URL looks like:

"https://www.example.com/us/en/abc/cde/index.html"

| Path | Represents |
| --- | --- |
| us/en | Country/Language |
| abc | Folder in structure group |
| cde | Subfolder in abc |
| index.html | The page to be unpublished |

Now index.html should be unpublished.

Comment: Have you seen this post? https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4524/how-to-get-a-pages-full-url-using-the-core-service?rq=1

Comment: Does this published URL match what's stored in Topology Manager and the hierarchy of your structure groups?

Answer (score 1):

**Reference sample Code for Unpublish PageByUrl using CoreService:**

```
using System;
using Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace CoreService.PublishPageByPageURL
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string structureGroupFolderId = "tcm:9-5-4"; //Unpublishing publication SG Root Id
            string[] destinationTargetUris = { "tcm:0-2-65538" }; // TargetId for Unpublish
            string pageUrl = "/index.html"; //PageURL for Unpublish

            ICoreService client = GetClientHttp("localhost", @"vagrant", @"vagrant");

            Console.WriteLine("Connected to CoreService with user " + client.GetCurrentUser().Title);

            OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData filter = new OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData
            {
                ItemTypes = new ItemType[] { ItemType.Page},
                BaseColumns = ListBaseColumns.Id,
                Recursive = true,
            };

            IEnumerable<XNode> pagesListXml = client.GetListXml(structureGroupFolderId, filter).Nodes();
            Console.WriteLine($"Total Pages: {pagesListXml.Count()} ");

            IDictionary<string, string> pagesURLs = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            foreach (XElement element in pagesListXml)
            {
                string pageId = element.Attribute("ID").Value;

                PageData page = client.Read(pageId, new ReadOptions()) as PageData;
                string pageURL = ((PublishLocationInfo)page.LocationInfo).PublishLocationUrl;

                pagesURLs.Add(pageURL, pageId);

                Console.WriteLine($"pageId: {pageId}, pageURL:{pageURL}");
            }

            if (pagesURLs.TryGetValue(pageUrl, out string pageUri))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"PageId: {pageUri}");

                // UnPublish the page
                var unpublishInstruction = new UnPublishInstructionData
                {
                    ResolveInstruction = new ResolveInstructionData()
                };
                PublishTransactionData[] unpublishTransactions = client.UnPublish(new[] { pageUri}, unpublishInstruction,
                                                                                destinationTargetUris, PublishPriority.Normal,
                                                                                new ReadOptions());
                Console.WriteLine("UnPublished page; transaction id: " + unpublishTransactions[0].Id);
            }

            Console.Read();
        }

        private static ICoreService GetClientHttp(string hostname, string username, string password)
        {
            var basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding
            {
                MaxBufferSize = 10485760, // 4MB
                MaxBufferPoolSize = 10485760,
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = 10485760,
                ReaderQuotas = new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()
                {
                    MaxStringContentLength = 10485760, // 4MB
                    MaxArrayLength = 10485760,
                },
                Security = new BasicHttpSecurity
                {
                    Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly,
                    Transport = new HttpTransportSecurity
                    {
                        ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows
                    }
                }
            };

            hostname = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", hostname.StartsWith("http") ? "" : "http://", hostname, hostname.EndsWith("/") ? "" : "/");
            var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(hostname + "webservices/CoreService201701.svc/basicHttp");
            var factory = new ChannelFactory<ICoreService>(basicHttpBinding, endpoint);
            factory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
            return factory.CreateChannel();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it helps